# Table Row (//tr) HtmlNodes seem to have issue with rows being skipped

Tags: c#, web-scraping, .net-core, html-table, html-agility-pack

I'm currently trying to scrape a cannabis strain database as it is no longer being maintained. I seem to be running into an issue where table rows are skipped in my logic but it really doesn't make sense, it's like a break is being called when I'm iterating through the //tr elements of the table that is storing the chemical reports.

Is it something like the δ α symbols in the next row. I've tried regex replacing them out to now luck. Any help would be appreciated all code is in a single class console app.

Issue is in the table.ChildNodes not iterating all the way through. Located in the ParseChemical() method.

Sample Page: http://ocpdb.pythonanywhere.com/ocpdb/420/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

namespace CScrape
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        private static readonly string BaseUri = "http://ocpdb.pythonanywhere.com/ocpdb/";
        private static int _startId = 420;
        private static int _endId = 1519;

        private static List<Lab> _labs = new List<Lab>();
        private static List<ChemicalItem> _chemicalItems = new List<ChemicalItem>();
        private static List<UnitOfMeasure> _uoms = new List<UnitOfMeasure>();
        private static List<Strain> _strains = new List<Strain>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
            _uoms.AddRange(GetUoms());
            for (var i = _startId; i <= _endId; i++)
            {
                var result = GetUri($"{BaseUri}{i}").Result;
                _strains.Add(ParseChemical(result));
            }

        }

        private static long AddChemicalItem(ChemicalItem item)
        {
            if (ChemicalExists(item.Symbol))
                return _chemicalItems.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.Symbol == item.Symbol)?.Id ?? -1;

            item.Id = _chemicalItems.Count + 1;
            _chemicalItems.Add(item);
            return item.Id;
        }

        private static void UpdateChemicalItem(ChemicalItem item)
        {
            if (!ChemicalExists(item.Symbol)) return;

            var index = _chemicalItems.IndexOf(item);
            if (!(index >= 0)) return;
            _chemicalItems.RemoveAt(index);
            AddChemicalItem(item);
        }

        private static long AddLab(Lab lab)
        {
            if (LabExists(lab.Name))
                return _labs.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == lab.Name)?.Id ?? -1;
            lab.Id = _labs.Count + 1;
            _labs.Add(lab);
            return lab.Id;
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetUri(string uri)
        {
            var response = await Client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
        }

        private static Strain ParseChemical(string html)
        {
            html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&Delta;", "Delta");
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            var strain = new Strain();
            strain.Reports ??= new List<ChemicalReport>();

                try
                {
                    strain.Name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/b").InnerText;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: DOcument Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strain.Name)) return null;

                try
                {
                    var ocpId = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/p/b/text()[1]");
                    strain.OcpId = SanitizeHtml(ocpId.InnerText).Split(':')[1];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Document Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strain.OcpId)) return null;

                try
                {
                    var date = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/p/text()");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Document Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                
                var chemReport = new ChemicalReport();
                chemReport.Items ??= new List<ReportItem>();
                try
                {
                    var table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody");
                    var children = table.ChildNodes.ToList();
// On the sample page there are 200 children here
// However it only interates through the first few and then just breaks out of the loop
                    foreach (var child in children)
                    {
                        var name = child.Name;
                        if (child.Name == "tr")
                        {
                            var infos = child.SelectNodes("th|td");
                            foreach (var info in infos)
                            {
                                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.InnerText)) continue;
                                if (info.InnerText.Contains("Report")) continue;
                                if (double.TryParse(info.InnerText, out var isNumber))
                                {
                                    var last = chemReport.Items.LastOrDefault();
                                    if (last == null) continue;
                                    if (last.Value <= 0.0000) last.Value = isNumber;
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var further = chemReport.Items.ToArray()[chemReport.Items.Count - 2];
                                        if (further.Value <= 0.0000)
                                            further.Value = isNumber;
                                    }

                                    continue;
                                }
                                
                                var _ = new ChemicalItem
                                {
                                    Name = info.InnerText,
                                    Symbol = info.InnerText
                                };
                                _.Id = AddChemicalItem(_);
                                var report = new ReportItem
                                {
                                    Chemical = _,
                                    ChemicalItemId = _.Id,
                                    UnitOfMeasureId = 1,
                                    UoM = GetUoms()[0]
                                };
                                chemReport.Items.Add(report);
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }

                    strain.Reports.Add(chemReport);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Document exception
                    Console.Write(e.Message);
                }


                return strain;
        }

        private static List<UnitOfMeasure> GetUoms()
        {
            return new List<UnitOfMeasure>
            {
                new UnitOfMeasure {Name = "Milligrams per Gram", Symbol = "mg/g"},
                new UnitOfMeasure {Name = "Percent", Symbol = "%"}
            };
        }

        private static string SanitizeHtml(string text, string replacement = "")
        {
            return Regex.Replace(text, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;|&alpha;|\n|\t", replacement);
        }

        private static string GetLabName(string[] split)
        {
            var strip = split[0].Split(':')[1];
            for(var i = 1; i < split.Length - 2; i ++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(split[i])) break;
                strip += $" {split[i]}";
            }

            return strip;
        }

        private static string GetSampleId(string[] split)
        {
            var found = false;
            foreach (var item in split)
            {
                if (found)
                    return item.Split(':')[1];
                if (item == "Sample") found = true;
            }

            return "NA";
        }

        private static bool LabExists(string name)
        {
            return _labs.Any(lab => lab.Name == name);
        }

        private static bool ChemicalExists(string name)
        {
            return _chemicalItems.Any(ci => ci.Symbol == name);
        }

        private static ReportItem GetReportItem(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) return null;
            ReportItem ri = null;
            try
            {
                var clean = SanitizeHtml(text);
                var check = 0;
                var split = clean.Split(':');
                var label = split[0];
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label)) return null;
                if (double.TryParse(label, out var invalidType)) return null;
                var val = string.Empty;
                if (split.Length == 1)
                {
                    if (split[0].Contains("Total"))
                    {
                        Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
                        Match result = re.Match(split[0]);

                        label = result.Groups[1].Value;
                        val = result.Groups[2].Value;
                    }
                }

                if(split.Length > 1)
                    val = split[1];
                if (!ChemicalExists(label)) AddChemicalItem(new ChemicalItem {Id = _chemicalItems.Count + 1,Symbol = label});
                ri = new ReportItem();
                ri.Chemical = _chemicalItems.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.Symbol == label);

                ri.UoM = val.Contains("%")
                    ? _uoms.FirstOrDefault(uom => uom.Symbol == "%")
                    : _uoms.FirstOrDefault(uom => uom.Symbol == "mg/g");

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) return ri;
                var value = val.Contains("%") ? split[1].Substring(0, val.Length - 1) : val;
                ri.Value = Convert.ToDouble(value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: Document Exception
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return ri;
        }

        //private static ChemicalItem GetChemicalItem(string text)
        //{

        //}

        public class Strain
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public DateTime Created { get; set; }

            public string OcpId { get; set; }

            public bool IsHidden { get; set; } = false;

            public virtual ICollection<ChemicalReport> Reports { get; set; }
        }

        public class Lab
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ChemicalReport> Reports { get; set; }
        }

        public class ChemicalReport
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("Lab")]
            public long LabId { get; set; }

            public virtual Lab Lab { get; set; }

            public string SampleId { get; set; }

            public DateTime Created { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ReportItem> Items { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("Strain")]
            public long StrainId { get; set; }

            public virtual Strain Strain { get; set; }
        }

        public class ChemicalItem
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Symbol { get; set; }
        }

        public class ReportItem
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("Chemical")]
            public long ChemicalItemId { get; set; }

            public virtual ChemicalItem Chemical { get; set; }

            public double Value { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("UoM")]
            public long UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }

            public virtual UnitOfMeasure UoM { get; set; }
        }

        public class UnitOfMeasure
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public string Symbol { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```